# Why is background-image of childelement ontop of parents background-color?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code:

```
#overlayouter
        {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: red;

            width: 900px;
            height: 900px;

            z-index: 100;
        }
        #overlayinner
        {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;

            z-index: 0;

            width: 900px;
            height: 900px;

            background-image: url(picurl);
            background-position: 0 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

HTML is just:

```
<div id="overlayouter">
    <div id="overlayinner">

    </div>    
</div>
```

I have a background image in a child div.

And I want a background-color in it's parent div, with rgb() (now it's just red).

But why is the child elements background ontop? Is it because an element can only have background-color OR background-image? And the child's kind takes presedence?

I want the parent div to have a rgba later which will make some type of overlay.

I have set up a jsfiddle showing the problem..
http://jsfiddle.net/9Rj9V/

Comment: Is `z-index: -1;` what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/9Rj9V/1/

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks. I thought z-indexes were just relative to eachother?

Comment: They are but come with some quirks depending on browsers etc. Glad you got it working either way, I've made it into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `z-index: 0;` to `z-index: -1;` for `#overlayinner`. jsfiddle.net/9Rj9V/1

Answer (score 4):

[Without z-index:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)
[image]

[With z-index:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index)
[image]

[The Stacking Context:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)
[image: With z-index]

> In summary:
>
> - Positioning and assigning a z-index value to an HTML element creates a stacking context, (as does assigning non-full opacity).
> - Stacking contexts can be contained in other stacking contexts, and together create a hierarchy of stacking contexts.
> - Each stacking context is completly independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.
> - Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking
>     order of the parent stacking context.
>     [-MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)